# javascript event handler: how to get reference to calling element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element with an event handler attached like this :

```
<button type="button" onClick="buttonUsed()">X</button>
```

The attached function is like this :

```
function buttonUsed() {
  this.innerHTML="used";
}
```

When user clicks the button, the button element should have the text "used". But when I click the button nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a reference to an element in the function call:

***HTML :***

```
 <button type="button" onClick="buttonUsed(this)">X</button>
```

***JavaScript :***

```
function buttonUsed(el) {
    el.innerHTML = "used";
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs3dc6ze/)